# Asymptotic posterior of learning

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

Suppose you have finite feature vectors $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\in \mathbb{R}^d$. For each vector $x_n$, you can observe noisy labels
\begin{equation*}
    y_{n,j} = f(x_n;W)+\epsilon_{n,j} \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
where $f(x_n;W)$ is the ground-truth value of $f$ at $x_n$ with unknown parameters $W\in {R^K}$, and $\epsilon_{n,j}\stackrel{i.i.d.}\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma_n^2\right)$. Now you impose a prior distribution on $W$, that is
\begin{equation*}
    W\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{0}_{K},\sigma^2_W\mathbf{I}_{K}\right).
\end{equation*} The data set is denoted by $\mathcal{D}=\left \{ \left ( x_n,y_{n,j} \right )  \right \}_{j=1,2,\ldots,m_n;n=1,2,\ldots,N}$.

Suppose you can generate independent $\widehat{W}_{k}, k=1,2,\ldots,K$ from $p(W\mid \mathcal{D})$. Given a fixed $x_n$, you can infer $f(x_n)$ with samples $f\left(x_n;\widehat{W}_{k}\right)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,K$. Prove that
When the number of observations $m_n\rightarrow \infty$ at a fixed $x_n$, then $\operatorname{Var}\left ( f\left ( x_n ;\widehat{W}_k \right )  \right )  \rightarrow 0$.
When the number of observations $m_n$ at a fixed $x_n$ is fixed, then $\operatorname{Var}\left ( f\left ( x_n ;\widehat{W}_k \right )  \right )  > 0$ even when $m_{n'}\rightarrow\infty$ for all other $x_{n'}$'s.
(You can add regularity conditions if necessary.)